# How to play with my cats?

Tags: cats, play

My cats are four years old and one of them always meows while I am using the computer, if I go to see what she wants, she just walks away, circles the sofa once and then stands there staring at me. As soon as I go back on the computer she does the same thing.

Usually I open the door for her to go outside but she doesn't want to go out 75% of the time.

I try to play with them regularly but they don't care for their toys, I throw stuff and jingle their toys and play with the "feathers on a stick" and they sit there staring at me. If they do interact with the toy, it's for about 3 seconds then they walk off. I try buying them new toys in case they're bored of the old ones but they still don't care about them.

I try to pick them up to cuddle them but they don't like it and want to get down (they are rescue kittens so they might have been held roughly in their past or something)

They have plenty of food, a fresh water bowl and a running water fountain so I don't think they are complaining about the catering service either.

If I can't pick up my cat and they're not interested in playing, what can I do to interact with them and why might one of them be trying to get my attention all the time?

Comment: If a human were in a cat body doing that, I'd think they were lonely and just wanted comfortable, calm attention and companionship.

Comment: Maybe she wants attention. See: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/9533

Answer (score 3):

You have three separate issues here:

1) Your cat does not want to play with the toys you have.

2) Your cats do not like to be picked up.

3) Your cat is meowing at you and you do not know what it means.

For #1 know that some cats are less playful than others. Also each cat has their own favorite toy. Try switching toy types. If your cats won't play with a laser pointer, string, or a feather on a fishing rod type toys, I would guess they are not that playful.

2: Most cats do not like being picked up without some kind of conditioning. This is due to their general dislike of being restrained or trapped. You can train (condition) them to like being picked up by picking them up briefly and holding them and then rewarding them with praise and a cat treat. 
Just pick them up for a few seconds at first, then slowly over time hold them longer and longer as they begin to tolerate it more. This whole process may take a month or more. Also make sure you are holding them comfortably. You can do a web search on “how to hold a cat.” If you are holding them incorrectly they will not like it and will struggle and want down.

3: Cats typically meow at their humans for only a handful of reasons.  If they are not hungry or want to go outside then odds are they want some attention. Attention usually means they want to be petted or have their heads scratched. Sometimes they will lead you away to a spot where they want you to pet them. Try following them and when they stop, give them a good 30 seconds of gentle petting. 
If this doesn’t work or you are having difficulties with 1 or 2 let us know and we can try something else.